# How to use One Laravel Controller with Multiple Guard instead of Duplicating the Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I have two Guards

```
Admin
User
```

Also i have created controllers where user can manage his own data and admin can also manage user data. So i created two Controllers

```
Controllers
    Admin
        EducatonBackgroundController
    User
        EducationBackgroundController
```

In User/EducationBackgroundController i have this function which fetch education background of a current logged user and display on the user view

```
 public function index(Education $education)
    {
        try {
            $educations = $education->where('user_id',$this->userLoggedID())->with('organization','program','country','city')->get();
            return view('users.education.index',compact('educations'));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

In Admin/EducationBackgroundController i have this function which fetch education background of all users and display on the admin view

```
 public function index(Education $education)
    {
        try {
            $educations = $education->with('organization','program','country','city','user')->get();
            return view('admin.users.education.index',compact('educations'));
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            abort(404);
        }
    }
```

From observation these functions are similar but differ on view return and data fetch.

So How can i create a one Controller which can be used by both Admin and User guards instead of duplicate Controller and View for both Guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar by adding a second set of routes, like this:

```
<?php

    Route::middleware(['auth:admin_api'])->group(function () {
        Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
            Route::name('api.admin.')->group(function () {

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                /// PLACE ADMIN API ROUTES HERE ////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                Route::apiResource('test','App\Http\Controllers\API\MyController');
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            });
        });
    });

    Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
        Route::name('api.')->group(function () {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /// PLACE PUBLIC API ROUTES HERE ///////////////////////////
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Route::apiResource('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\MyController');
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        });
    });
```

So when an admin user goes to admin/test, it uses the admin auth guard, and when a normal user goes to /test it uses the standard auth guard. Both of these use the same controller.

I then created a base controller for my app. Here is how I determined with guard is being used to access the route in the constructor:

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    protected $user;

    protected $isAdmin = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(Auth::guard('admin_api')->check()) {
            $this->user = Auth::guard('admin_api')->user();
            $this->isAdmin = true;
        } elseif(Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
            $this->user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
            $this->isAdmin = false;
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Not Authorized',
            ], 401);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you. I already have separate routes for each guard but i want one method to be accessible by all guards and redirect t respective views instead of creating view and controller method for each guard

Comment: Yes. That is why in the constructor for the controller I have it checking which guard is using to authenticate. In the method, you can check if($isAdmin), and take different actions depending on the type of user.